# How do I enjoy Unity 2D in Ubuntu 12.10 with a computer that is capable of running Unity 3D?

Tags: dell, unity-2d, inspiron, 12.10

In the upcoming Ubuntu 12.10 - Unity 2D will be removed. 
Thanks to LLVMpipe, a computer that isn't capable of running Unity 3D is getting the same experience without the Compiz effects.

But what if I don't want Unity 3D at all? I have a Dell Inspiron 1525 that's capable to run Unity 3D, yet it's slow. Very slow. Unity 2D, however, is faster. How do I enjoy the snappiness of 2D from 12.10?

Comment: One simple suggestion would be ,try other available DE's of Ubuntu :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at [Unity going forward](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-August/035632.html) for an idea on the current understanding of how older machines may cope.

> As I mentioned, this approach is a work in progress as we tweak the
>   experience and effects to maximize the performance. We expect this to
>   shake out over the rest of this cycle and bleed into 13.04 as well. ...
>   Still, with all the above, there will be systems that are simply too
>   old to run Unity. In those cases it would be necessary to either stick
>   with 12.04 LTS or run another [desktop
>   environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available).

Comment: "Older machines"... How about "People who don't want the buggy POS that's called Compiz"?